# Fullcalendar: how to get events from two variables and pass to through 'eventAfterRender'?

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, fullcalendar

I have the two types of events , namely 'holidays' and 'events', which should be received from two variables. The variables are holding the ajax responses. Now I want to pass the holidays and events to the calendar as 'events'. I do not know how to pass the variables. The following is my ajax  code, which is declared to variable. Is my code correct?

```
var return_holidays = function() { 
var holdays = [];
$.ajax({
        url: "/calendar/show_holidays",
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetch',
        async: true,

        success: function(s)
            {
           //alert(s);
              holdays = s;
              }
    });
    return holdays;
}();    
var return_events = function() {
var dynamic_events = [];    
$.ajax({
        url: "calendar/show_events",
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetch_events',
        async: true,

         success: function(s)
         {//alert(s);
         dynamic_events = s;
          }
    });
    return dynamic_events;
}();     


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 

utc: true, 
header: { 
left: 'prev,next today', 
center: 'title', 
right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
}, 
editable: true, 
droppable: true, 
eventSources: [return_holidays, return_events],//am calling the variables
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) { 
element.append(event.title); 
} 

});
```

Can i achieve in this way? Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of return_holidays, return_events should be JSON, so you could try returning `JSON.stringify(yourArray);` instead of a plain array. You could also try letting the calendar deal with the fetching business:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        {
            url: '/calendar/show_holidays',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'type' : 'fetch'
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching holidays!');
            },
        },
        {
            url: '/calendar/show_events',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'type' : 'fetch_events'
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
        }
    ]
});
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

Alternatively you can pass the urls directly to the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        '/calendar/show_holidays',
        'calendar/show_events'
    ]
});
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/eventSources/

Always make sure that you are retuning objects in JSON format from your backend.

Comment: yah peer thanks for the link, don t forget to give me a upvote..:)